# Generate Next Sequence When No Value is Provided

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a bigint column which is not unique. I want to be able to set the value of this column on inserts but when no value is provided, I would like to auto generate the next sequence in the column of numbers.

Is this possible to do in a synchronised way? The new value needs to be unique with no possibility of the same number being generated when two records are inserted simultaneously.

Comment: You need to do this generating within a transaction. This way, you won't get the same *bigint* number generated by two threads.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the table itself, using functions and a trigger perhaps?

Comment: sounds llike you need to cleanse your data and then add a primary/unique key constraint

Comment: What @Tanner suggested would be better to do, but if you **really need** to have duplicates there then doing it with `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger would be your best bet. This way, within the trigger code, you can find out what the next *bigint* number you need to insert (by using a transaction so you don't get two connections doing it at the same time).

Comment: I would suggest having *another* column that is the identity column.  A column that can be `NULL` or have a value does not sound like a "key" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Sequence object in your database and when no value has been explicitly provided to the insert statement, retrieve the next value from the Sequence to insert instead. The logic for this can be implemented in a trigger.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx

As others have suggested, an Identity column would better though.

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.